# Update column with a dynamic sequence with Row_number()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to update in MSSQL a column(Y) of a table(A) with with an ascending sequence that resets itself when the value of another column(X) of the same table changes.
Table A at the beginning:

| id | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |

As it should be after the script:

| id | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |

I tried with row_number() but in the loop, it modify all the rows  :
With a counter and variable to increment:

```
UPDATE dbo.A
SET "Y" = @MyInc
FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( "Id" ASC) AS row_num_Id
             , Id
             , X
             , Y
        FROM dbo.A)     AS sub
        WHERE row_num_Id = @MyCounter;
```

Comment: You need a `PARTITION BY` clause in your `OVER`. Also, `OVER ( "Id" ASC)` isn't valid. Is that `ORDER BY "ID"`?

Comment: Yes `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X ORDER BY id) as row_num`

Comment: Yes, i wirte it wrong, i have a table a little more complicated. 
`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY X ORDER BY "Id","C") AS row_num_Id
 , "C"
, "Id"
FROM dbo.A)  AS sub`
but it change the same all the rows

Comment: Don't think you need the Id and C in double quotes, remove the double quotes and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the results you want

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
    Id INT NOT NULL, 
    X INT NOT NULL, 
    Y INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #T(Id, X, Y)
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 2, 1),
(4, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 1),
(6, 3, 1);

GO

WITH WithRowNumbers AS (
    SELECT 
    Id, 
    X, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Id) As RowNumber
    FROM #T
)

UPDATE T 
SET Y = WRN.RowNumber
FROM WithRowNumbers AS WRN
INNER JOIN #T AS T ON T.Id = WRN.Id

SELECT * FROM #T
```

Or as @CharlieFace mentions you can simplify even more, as the CTE is like a view of the original table.

```
UPDATE T 
SET Y = T.RowNumber
FROM WithRowNumbers AS T;
```

Comment: There is no need for a join, you can update `WithRowNumbers` directly https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2a8eb253f02d015177cd6fccd08623d

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks @Charlieface I dont use CTE to update very often, so appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Perfect, it works like i want. Thanks to both of you